# Strategies of merging master

Tags: git, github, merge

So if I'm working in a branch, let's call it `feature-foo`, that was initially based of `master`. And I'm continuously adding many commits to it.

- At that same time, my colleague is working on a `feature-baz`, decides to merge it his branch into master.
- Then we find out that `feature-foo` depends on certain changes that now currently in master. I would merge master into my `feature-foo` branch and continue building `feature-foo`
- At some point I'm ready to merge it back to master, but then my colleagues already merged some other changes to master and now I have conflicts, and can't easily merge my `feature-foo` back.
- It seems it's easier to resolve conflicts if instead of merging master into `feature-foo` I would start a new branch off of master and then merge `feature-foo` into that branch. So, I would create `feature-foo-2` (basing it off of current master) and then merge `feature-foo` into `feature-foo-2`, and fix conflicts on the way.
- And now, my `feature-2` branch is conflicts free and ready to be merged to master.

So my question is: maybe I'm doing something wrong? Is there an easier way to handle that all?
What is the best way of dealing with changing master?
Should I always try to rebase and squash commits before merging any other branches into mine? Because apparently it's not recommended to squash commits after you merge things from other branches.

We're not using git-flow. As I understand it - I can't use it for my own benefit, entire group has to agree to use it, right?
What are your thoughts?

**upd:** Of course I forgot to mention that I can't push into orgin/master (that's how our github repo configured). Any merges to master should go through pull requests. 
So you see, that even if I make something small in my local branch, in order to have a PR accepted, I would have to merge/rebase master onto it. But master by that time could already have way more and in reality it makes it simpler to rebase/merge my branch into master (rather than other way around). But since I can't push master to origin, I have to create a temporary branch (based off of master) and then merge/rebase my changes onto that, and create a PR based on that temporary branch.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad.  There is nothing wrong with merging the remote `master` into your branch to bring it up to date.

Comment: Agreed. It is more about personal taste. Like, I prefer `rebase` over `merge`, when I work on my own local branch.

Comment: @EvenYoung so maybe that's the answer - instead of merging master into my own branches, I should always try to rebase from master onto my branches?

Answer (score 1):

If the features are small enough, I'd opt to rebase and merge with the "no fast-forward" (--no-ff) option when its time to check in.  It is a matter of preference - I prefer to keep master clean by ensuring that there are no overlapping branches.

[image]

FYI, to visualize your tree and all your branches:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate=short
```

Comment: my problem is that even if my branch adds very little, by the time I'm ready to merge to master, master changes significantly. And now it's easier to merge/rebase my feature into master (rather than other way around). But I can't merge directly to master - it has to be through a pull request (that's how our Github configured). 
So now, I have to create a temporary branch of off master, merge/rebase my stuff to it, and issue a PR based on that temporary branch. 
And I was wondering if that can be simplified.

Comment: if your branch adds very little, and master changes a lot over time, that's the perfect candidate to rebase onto master first before merging into master. I don't understand why one would merge first, then rebase.

Comment: When you create a temp branch (off of the tip of master), and then merge your changes into that, you are essentially doing the same thing as a rebase from your branch onto master.  So rather than create a tmp branch, just rebase onto master, handle any conflicts, push to your dev branch to the remote repository, then submit a pull request. Much shorter

Comment: But I can't push onto origin/master (it won't allow me)

Comment: just to clarify: we're not using forks. Master is our "release" branch. So we're creating PRs onto master

Comment: That's fine. Forks doesn't play into this. When I say 'rebase onto master', i mean do a "git rebase master" from your dev branch. The rebase still happens on your dev branch.  Its as if you branched off of the tip of master when you did your work (you actually didn't, but it appears as if you did).

Comment: Oh, I think I now understand what you mean... Jeez. Apparently I had complete lack of understanding how rebase works. "Rebase onto master" doesn't mean that you would change master, it's other way around.

Comment: When you rebase your dev branch, and you do it periodically, you'll eventually have to do a force push, to overwrite the dev branch that's on the server.  That's because you're re-writing history. But that should also be ok, if you're the only one working on the dev branch. If its shared, you have to be careful about rebasing.

Comment: another problem of rebasing - it makes it slightly difficult to revert changes. With merge - you have to revert just the last commit.